# C++ Link list insert swop

Tags: c++, linked-list

I want to insert 2 into 4 and 4 into 2. I am getting errors with the swop. How would I fix the code below to get the swop.

```
#include <iostream>

struct nodeType
{
    int info ;
    nodeType* link ;
};

int main()
{
    nodeType* ptr ;
    nodeType* list ;

    ptr = new nodeType;
    ptr->info = 1;
    list = new nodeType;
    ptr->info = 2;
    list->link = ptr;
    ptr = new nodeType;
    ptr->info = 3;
    ptr = new nodeType;
    list->info = 4;
    ptr->link = NULL;
    list->link->link->link = ptr;

    unsigned count = 1 ;
    ptr = list ;
    while ( ptr )
    {
        std::cout << "Node #" << count++ << ':' << ptr->info << '\n' ;
        ptr = ptr->link ;
    }
}
```

I have tried various ways to get the swop to occur , but I am getting compiler errors.
Thanks

Comment: "I am getting compiler errors"... Always copy the compiler error please...

Comment: rather than ptr->info = 2; I think you mean list->info = 2;

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how pointers work. I advise you to try something simpler first, like constructing two nodes and linking one to the other.

Comment: You are getting a `runtime error`, and more concretely, "An Access Violation" which is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
nodeType* ptr ;
nodeType* list ;

ptr = new nodeType;
ptr->info = 1;
```

The pointer `ptr` now points to a node which contains `1`.

```
list = new nodeType;
ptr->info = 2;
```

Now `list` points to a node, and the node which `ptr` points to contains `2`.

```
list->link = ptr;
```

Now one node is connected to the other.

```
ptr = new nodeType;
ptr->info = 3;
```

Now `ptr` points to another node, containing `3`.

```
ptr = new nodeType;
```

Now `ptr` points to *another* node, and the node containing `3` has been lost.

```
list->info = 4;
```

Now the first node in the list contains `4`.

```
ptr->link = NULL;
```

All right.

```
list->link->link->link = ptr;
```

Now you are trying to iterate past the end of the list (which has only two nodes). You dereference an invalid pointer, which causes undefined behavior; you're lucky if all you get is an access violation error.

You must study pointers some more before you attempt a swap in the middle of a list.

Comment: @user1291092 Draw pictures with pencil and paper on 1) The intended node and list interaction. 2) The code's action on the node and list (e.g. This drawing will not match the picture in 1) until the code is modified).